# How to create date slicer for start date and end date

Tags: powerbi

I have two columns in my table. Issue_start_date and issue_end_date.i want to create a date slicer between them.

On left side it should be start date and right side of slicer it should be the end date.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Date table separate from your data table that you will use for you slicer. You can create a Calculated Table with the following:

```
DateTable = 
  var minD = MIN('YourDataTable'[Issue_start_date])
  var maxD = MAX('YourDataTable'[Issue_end_date])
  return
    CALENDAR(
      DATE( YEAR(minD), 1, 1),
      DATE( YEAR(maxD), 12, 31)
   )
```

Use the above for your slicer and set it's Style to `Between`. Ensure no relationship exists between `DateTable` and `'YourDataTable'` table.

Next, you will need to create a measure for the "filtering/slicing". Create one similar to:

```
Issue count =
  var minD = MIN('DateTable'[Date])  // start range of slicer
  var maxD = MAX('DateTable'[Date])  // end range of slicer
  return
    COUNTROWS(
      FILTER(
        'YourDataTable', 
        // adjust the following to your need
        [Issue_start_date] >= minD &&
        [Issue_end_date] <= maxD
      )
    )
```

Lastly, add this new measure to your visuals or to the Filter pane on the right, under `Filter on this visual` and set it to `is not blank`.

---

If you already have a Date table and it has a relationship, then you will need to use `ALL` or `REMOVEFILTERS` or other similar functions. Try for example:

```
Issue count =
  var minD = MIN('DateTable'[Date])  // start range of slicer
  var maxD = MAX('DateTable'[Date])  // end range of slicer
  return
    CALCUALTE(
      COUNTROWS('YourDataTable'),
      REMOVEFILTERS('DateTable'),
      // adjust the following to your need
      'YourDataTable'[Issue_start_date] >= minD &&
      'YourDataTable'[Issue_end_date] <= maxD
    )
```

Comment: I already have a date table and having a relationship with the existing date column that is a problem

Comment: See bottom part of the updated answer above.